# How do I detach a disk from an Azure VM so I can re-attach it to another?

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, azure

I have an Azure VM with a data disk attached and mounted in a folder in c:\ - the VM is bricked after uninstalling .NET 4.5 (don't do that on 2012 R2).

I have created a new VM. Now how do I detach my data disk and reattach it to the new VM?

The detach disk option for the VM only lists its primary C: system disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following guide to do that:

[Recover Azure VM by attaching OS disk to another Azure VM - Microsoft Azure Support Team Blog - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2014/11/20/recovering-azure-vm-by-attaching-os-disk-to-another-azure-vm.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Alexus pointed towards a link with the solution, though for StackOverflow, we should always pull out the salient points and post them here.

- Delete the old VM, choose to keep the disks.
- Restart the portal, this is important since the UI controls availability (show|hide) is computed once on load.
- With the new VM highlighted, from the bottom menu, choose Attach > Existing Disk. When all disks are assigned to VMs, only Attach > "Empty Disk" is an option.
- Choose the disk to attach.
- RDP to the VM and mount the volume in Disk Manager.

Comment: Indeed the link Alexus posted is now broken. Thanks for this.